# xmlpath and one or more series of xmlstarlet commands to edit XML child element value based on instances of repeated parent element

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Input xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test_01.swift'>
            <failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'>warning: Line:10 </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test_02.swift'>
            <failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'>warning: Line:11 </failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test_01.swift'>
            <failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'>debug_line_1 ></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test_02.swift'>
            <failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'>debug_line_2 ></failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I know this will get me the number of nodes elements testcase:

```
`xmlstarlet sel  -t -c "count(//*/testcase)" filename.xml`
```

on bash the above line would return:
2

I need an xpath (or more if cant be done is one pass) expressions with a function that I could use to replace the child node element value failure with a hardcoded one that goes according to the instance of the parent test case. For example (as per output):

Instance 1 of

*testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test_01.swift'*

Original value of

*failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'*

is **warning: Line:10**

New Value will be:

***debug_line_1***

For all consecutive node elements *testcase* its children value should increase by 1:

Next testcase element value would be

***debug_line_2***

And so forth...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very efficient, but you could count preceding `testcase` elements...

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//testcase/*' -x 'concat("debug_line_",count(preceding::testcase)+1)' input.xml
```